# How can I log into an existing remote session using FreeNX?

Tags: remote-access, freenx

I successfully installed FreeNX server and the QtNX client. When I connect to the server, the screen does not reflect my current desktop on the server, but a newly spawned session.

How can I have FreeNX show me the existing state of the desktop on the server instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an alternate VNC server. If you are using VNC over an untrusted network (internet) you should tunnel over SSH.

Vino is the default (shared desktop), but x11vncserver or tightvncserver will also work.

For additional information see:

See : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers